# Capture image from touch of PixelSense-compatible PC and save it as .bmp

Tags: c#, image, bitmapimage, pixelsense

I'm using Microsoft Surface 2.0 SDK with SUR40 PixelSense compatible computer. I need to capture image from it's touch and save it as `.bmp`. Since Surface SDK comes with RawImageVisualizer example, which displays picture from touch on the screen, I've tried to modify program for writing picture to HDD. The problem is, I get `ArgumentException: Parameter is invalid` during building `Image` from byte array captured from touch.

This is how I retrieve byte array with image data from `FrameReceivedEventArgs` on `FrameReceived` event:

```
event.UpdateRawImage(
                ImageType.Normalized,
                normalizedImage,
                0, 0,
                InteractiveSurface.PrimarySurfaceDevice.WorkingAreaWidth,
                InteractiveSurface.PrimarySurfaceDevice.WorkingAreaHeight);
```

And that's how I try to write bytes as `.bmp` to disk:

```
System.Drawing.Image img;
using (System.Drawing.Image raw = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(normalizedImage)))
{
    img = raw.Clone() as System.Drawing.Bitmap;
}
img.Save("C:/img.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

So I get the exception trying to create `Image` from stream. Nevertheless this byte array works totally fine with `Texture2D` and `SpriteBatch` which displays it. How can I fix `ArgumentException`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've just realized, that `UpdateRawImage` does not return a byte representation of `PNG` file, but only an array of pixels. So, to build an image from it, one have to write all other parts of file structure to the array: header and color table (if needed). In many cases this can be simply done with one of `System.Drawing.Bitmap` constructors:

```
public Bitmap(
    int width,
    int height,
    int stride,
    PixelFormat format,
    IntPtr scan0
)
```

But I was not so lucky, because `UpdateRawImage` returns 8bpp grayscale pixels, and `PixelFormat` enum doesn't support them (the most close is `Format16bppGrayScale`, but it uses 2 bytes for pixel, not one). So, in this particular situation, there are two obvious solutions. The first is making a new array of pixels, which meets one of `PixelFormat` standards (that was my choice, because I need 24-bit RGB image, despite it's actually black-white with only 256 shades). The second is writing `BMP` headers manually (and it's not very difficult due to open specs).